# What are high energy photons?

Tags: energy, photons

I have often read the term High Energy photons, does this mean that there do exist photons with low energy? Aren't they supposed to have constant energy according to $E= h\nu$?

Comment: $\nu$ is the frequency of the wave. You get photons with high frequency, e.g. gamma rays, and photons with low frequency, e.g. radio waves, and since the frequency varies so does the energy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each photon has a different wavelength $\lambda$, which determines the energy of the photon. For example, blue photons you observe with your eyes have a wavelength of $400 nm$. Using that $\nu = \frac{c}{\lambda}$ and $E= h\nu$ we can calculate it's energy: $3.1 eV$. A gamma-ray has a much smaller wavelength, smaller then $1 pm$ ($10^{-12}m$). That corresponds with an energy of $1.24 \dot{} 10^6 eV$, a factor $10^6$ higher. Photons with a energy in the order of this, or higher, are considered High Energy Photons

Answer (score 3):

High energy photons mean the photons whose frequency is very high.(relatively)
 If the frequency is high then from this equation 
$$E=hf$$
(where $E$ is energy
and 'h' is Planck's constant.)
energy is also high.
Thats what we really mean when we talk about high energy photons.

By high energy photons we ''usually'' mean gamma photons or X-ray photons .

Frequency ,wavelenght,and energy of infrared radiation:
Frequencies: .003 - 4 x 1014Hz

Wavelengths: 1 mm - 750 nm

Quantum energies: 0.0012 - 1.65 eV

similarly for visible light.
Frequencies: 4 - 7.5 x 1014Hz

Wavelengths: 750 - 400 nm

Quantum energies: 1.65 - 3.1 eV

Ultraviolet radiation:
Frequencies: 7.5 x 1014- 3 x 1016Hz

Wavelengths: 400 nm - 10 nm

Quantum energies: 3.1 - 124 eV

X-rays:
Frequencies: 3 x 1016Hz upward

Wavelengths: 10 nm - > downward

Quantum energies: 124 eV -> upward

Gamma-Rays:
Frequencies: typically >1020Hz

Wavelengths: typically < 10-12m

Quantum energies: typically >1 MeV

here you can see the photons whose frequencies are high energies are also high.
So we say they are high energy photons.(relatively)

source:http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ems3.html

Answer (score 1):

$\nu$ is the wavenumber (related to frequency by a factor of $2\pi$) - this is variable, and for visible light, how we perceive different colours.

Some [typical frequencies](http://www.davidterr.com/science-articles/electromagnetic_spectrum.html) for visible light and photons in bands of lower energies:

- Radio wave: 30Hz - 3GHz
- Microwave: 3GHz - 300GHz
- Infrared light: 300GHz - 400THz
- Visible light: 400THz - 800THz